# Resizing secondary drives online without interrupting virtual guests

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, partition

Ok. Imagine you end up in a scenario with multiple slave VMs that are all precreated from the same template leaving all of them with the unified disk size. When you need to run something bigger on some of that VMs, like database, it's pretty natural to create another disk to hold the database so it would be separated from system data. Easier to manage, easier to backup, etc. But how you would extend those disks?

Buy default it's normal to label all disks with MBR and create a huge partition on it. But you are effectively shooting your leg with it: you can't expand such partition online. In case you first choose to use RAW disk or create an LVM with one huge partition you could just resize it after expanding underlying volume, but in case with MBR you can't. You need to stop the service, unmount the partition, edit MBR... That's interruptive and undesirable.

So I have `/dev/sdb1` mounted on `/mnt` and I want to part with service takedowns. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The key to the answer is: you need to stop using MBR/GPT. When mounting an MBR partition the kernel locks the partition table and it can't be changed. You need to unmount. So the first time would be interruptive. But after small reconfiguration we will be good to go.

```
umount /mnt
sgdisk -p /dev/sdb
```

In the printed lines you need to write down a few numbers. They are required if you want to proceed or rollbeck.

`Logical sector size:`*`512`*`bytes` <- this is sector size, it defaults to 512 but please do remember to check.

`Number  Start (sector) ...`

`1`           *`2048`*  `...` <- starting sector of your partition, again this is default but please do remember to check.

So our partition start offset in bytes is 1048576. Now we can remove MBR and mount partition directly:

```
sgdisk -d 1 /dev/sdb1
mount -t ext4 -o offset=1048576 /dev/sdb /mnt
```

This way you are not mounting disk directly but creating a `loop` device with only the required part of original disk. Such devices can be manipulated with `losetup`.

From now on the disk is mounted directly without any partitions. The disk resize process would look like:

```
# resize partition in VMWare/VirtualBox/Xen/nameit
# remember to put real numbers in here
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/#\:#\:#\:#/device/rescan
losetup -c /dev/loop0
resize2fs /dev/loop0
```

If you want to get back to your original MBR you can do that too. Shrink you partition (to leave some space at the end of the disk), unmount the disk and recreate the partition specifying correct start sector.